# Error casting varchar to decimal even though SQL query doesn't return any results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query which fetches no rows. I am using cast function in select statement to cast from varchar to decimal, I am getting exception saying couldn't cast varchar to decimal.

This is my query

```
select distinct 
    order_id, order_amt, 
    cast(replace(order_amt, ',', '') as decimal(11, 2)) as amt 
from 
    table1 
left join 
    table2 on table1.order_id = table2.order_num
where 
    table2.order_num is null
    and table1.order_id not in (123, 456)
```

Not sure why I am getting error, even though query returns no results.

Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: A good reason to use the correct datatypes i.e. use a numerical type for numerical data.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have control over where SQL Server decides to evaluate expressions.  So, expressions might be evaluated (and generate an error), even on rows that are filtered out.

In this case, there is a very simply solution:  `try_cast()`:

```
Try_Cast(Replace(order_amt, ',', '') as decimal(11,2)) as amt
```

Comment: The same query used to run fine in sql server 2016 but is throwing error in 2019 version. Any idea?

Comment: Query plans change @VenkataB . If you want to consume values as a numerical values then fix the design; then these problems don't occur .